# Setting the top level navigation sort order with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've created a few sites using this command,

```
> New-SPWeb -url "http://server" -Template "STS#0" -Name "test99" -Description "test99" -UseParentTopNav
```

The sites are appearing in the navigation bar as expected but not in the order I would like them.

With this page `_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx` under `Navigation Editing and Sorting` I can change the order they appear in, but is this possible using PowerShell?

I found this page - [managing-quick-launch-current](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/04/managing-quick-launch-current.html) - which appears to do something similar with QuickLaunch. But it doesnt appear to manually set the sort order.

Comment: It's certainly possible because it can be done from .NET. Here's a starting point for [adding a link](http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/Adding+new+links+to+the+Top+Navigation+Bar+using+PowerShell) (for 2007 but can be adapted). Hopefully the TopNavigationBar property is populated in 2010 (wasn't in 2007) or you may need to [populate it yourself](http://www.thekickboard.com/archive/2010/09/01/programmatically-setting-navigation-order-in-a-moss-publishing-site.aspx).

Comment: AFAIK it's only populated for publishing sites. Above is a Team Site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following [URL](http://wsstopnavdsl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Use%20PowerShell%20with%20SharePoint%20Object%20Model&referringTitle=PowerShell%20code%20generator) gives an example.

Below is a small adaptation :

```
$url = "http://localhost:29688"
$topsite = Get-SPSite $url; 
$topweb = $topsite.OpenWeb()
$topnavs = $topweb.Navigation.TopNavigationBar


//this adds removes the first  navigation item in the topNav andadds it as a child itemn of the "Solutions" item
 $node0 = $topnavs[0]
 $node0.Children.Delete($node0.Children[0])}
$node1 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode -argumentlist @("Solutions", "/solutions", $False)
$node1 = $node0.Children.AddAsLast($node1)
```