# Automatically sort quicklaunch items

Tags: master-page, quick-launch

We can sort quicklaunch items directly on a website or [with powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11622/setting-the-top-level-navigation-sort-order-with-powershell) (see a [great tutorial here](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/04/managing-quick-launch-current.html)).

But is there an option to tell [SharePoint:AspMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466994.aspx) in masterpage to automatically sort the quicklaunch items?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: SP 2010 is the version I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the masterpage for each site collection is going to be significantly more work than configuring this the appropriate way. This is the kind of setting where the powershell script you reference makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option directly in the UI under Site Settings - Navigation - Sorting to automatically sort the list of links.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to avoid - to change manually.

Comment: One of the Sorting options is: "Automatically" that sorts the items in the navigation so they don't have to be managed manually.  Once set, items in the navigation are always sorted.  Are you looking to sort them some way other than alphabetically?

Comment: I want to sort it alphabetically

Comment: Then the out of the box setting should work fine for you.  Simply set the value in "Site Settings -> Navigation -> Sorting" to "Automatically"

Comment: I am trying to avoid that - to change manually, there are too many sites... My question is still if there is an attribute in sharepoint:aspmenu for sorting behavior.

Comment: I am a little confused because the Automatic option does exactly what you are asking for in your question - it sorts quick launch alphabetically.  Is there something else going on that is preventing you from using the Automatic setting?

Comment: @AnatolyMironov Modifying the masterpage for each site collection is going to be significantly more work than configuring this the appropriate way.  This is the kind of setting where the powershell script you reference makes the most sense.

Comment: @MikeOryszak, thank you for your comment. It has been a while I asked this question. I agree, a powershell script makes most sense. Could you post it as answer, so I can mark the right answer as solution?